# Django serializer classes referencing each other

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to have two serializer classes referencing each other but I'm getting one of the classes not defined if both classes are referencing each other.  I created a duplicate of one of the class w/ a difference name and this seems to work but is there a better way to do this without making 3 classes?

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    name = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'name',)

class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    artist = ArtistSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('id', 'artist', 'title',)

class ArtistSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    name = serializers.CharField()
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'slug', 'tracks')
```

Comment: It's a circular reference. Why do you need one at all?

Comment: because I want to show Artist name reference in Track details and all associated tracks in Artist details

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, it works. But found out my solution doesn't really work after all since I need to refence the specific Serializer class in the viewset class. Would have preferred a way to reference both serializer classses to each other but after some research it seems it's bad practice to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a circular class dependency. Your solution is one of the work arounds available for it. Another option is to avoid the circular dependecy all together by using a [StringRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

> StringRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the
>   relationship using its **unicode** method.

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'slug', 'tracks')

class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    artist = StringRelatedField()  # read only by default.
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('id', 'artist', 'title',)
```